# Cindent options seem to do nothing when editing .scm file

Tags: vim, scheme, racket

I am trying to use cindent to automatically indent a scheme/racket file. What I am currently getting with these options: set cino=(s,U1,)0,m1 is:

```
    (test
      (myStuff 1)
      )
```

Also, I would expect `(myStuff 1)` code to be indent 1 shiftwidth from `(test`, but it is not. In fact, changing the shiftwidth seems to have no impact on this. I have already verified that cindent is on.

What I really want is:

```
     (test
     'shiftwidth'(myStuff 1)
     ) <---- This is aligned with '(' in (test.
```

My .vimrc file looks like this:

```
 set nocompatible
 set ai 
 set shiftwidth=3
 set tabstop=3
 filetype off
 filetype plugin indent on
```

Here is another example of what I am getting:

```
    ; This is what my indentation currently looks like...
    (this is
          (not what) ; shifted over to line-up with the "i" in is.  
          (I want)
          (to happen)
          )           ; closing paren does NOT line up with opening. 

    ; This is what I want my indentation to look like...
    (this IS
       (what) ;This is shifted over by SHIFT width
       (I want)
       (to happen)
    ) ; This is on the same column as opening paren
```

As far as I can tell, this is loading the lisp syntax rules. And just to be sure, I have forced it to be lisp using `:set syntax=lisp`. As another note, whenever I set the syntax to ANY syntax type, this never changes the way these lines are indented. I've tried this list of syntax rules and all of them indent the same way:

```
     :set syntax=cpp
     :set syntax=php
     :set syntax=lisp
     :set syntax=ruby 
     ... etc.
```

Why is this not changing with any syntax that I change to? I'm at the point now where I feel like I just need to write a python or perl script to do my formatting because I can't seem to configure vim to do the proper formatting here.

Comment: Switching between `smartindent` and `auotindent` doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

'cindent' is really only meant for indenting C or C-like languages. Scheme is not even remotely c-like, it is lisp.

Try setting 'lisp' and 'autoindent' instead of 'cindent'. Even better, use the filetype-specific indent rules defined in Vim, by adding `filetype indent plugin on` to your .vimrc.

Note that filetype plugins often override settings you've set in your .vimrc. 'cindent' especially will almost always be overridden by filetype indent scripts, and sometimes 'cino' as well.

Comment: I understand that it is for formatting C, but I wanted to something I could leverage already. The thing is, is that my .vimrc file used to work for older version of vim, and when I switched to a newer version, it does't seem to indent the way I had things setup which has been killing me. The auto indent file that Lisp uses has almost nothing inside of it so turning the auto indent on or off seems to have no effect. Furthermore, if I `:set syntax=cpp` and attempt to change the parentheses behavior, it doesn't do anything. I could set `cino=(100s,U100,)100,m100 and reindenting does nothing.